# Is it reasonable to get a React "Maximum update depth exceeded" without accidental recursion?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, cesiumjs, resium

I'm writing a Cesium/Resium app with ~12000 clickable, animated points.
I'm getting the React warning `Maximum update depth exceeded`.
When there are <5000 points, there's no warning, but somewhere in the 7-8000 range, I tend to see this warning.
When debugging in the browser, my call stack is a lot of `recursivelyTraverseMutationEffects` followed by a lot of `postMessage (async)`

I already eliminated 2 sources of that warning that *were* silly recursion. I had a `useEffect`that was updating its trigger.

Is this warning a sign the app needs to be optimized or a sign that there's some silly recursive rendering happening?

Comment: What do you mean by "recursion" here?

Comment: Recursion like setting a state in a `useEffect` that triggers a `useEffect` that triggers a `useEffect` that triggers a `useEffect`

Comment: Without your code, it's impossible to tell.

Comment: @InSync wish I could mark that as the answer. Now I know there's not some issue that an experienced developer could spot from the symptoms alone

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Yes.**
It is reasonable to get a React "Maximum update depth exceeded" without accidental recursion.
We experimented with render size and made the entities teeny tiny, and now we can display many more entities before hitting the `Maximum update depth exceeded` warning.

Cesium/Resium struggles to render so many pixels while our app is doing other things in the browser.
The stack ends up too tall because we're asking for too much, and not because we're causing a bad update loop.

Answer (score 0):

This is an error, you need to fix it.

Depending on the full error message, this error means

- at least that there is **unnecessary work done**, making your app very slow, or
- React **will stop** its work at this error, so your app will likely be broken or have content missing.